# Upload File to remote server using Nodejs Multer

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express, sftp, multer

Can Nodejs Multer be used to upload files on remote server? If yes, then where do I provide the host name, host credentials, etc?

Comment: How is this related to kraken.js?

Comment: I am using Multer with Kraken so tagged Kraken here also.

Comment: I removed Kraken from tags as I agree this tag didn't make sense to this question. Thanks HeadCode!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my current knowledge and based on Multer API documentation, I don't think Multer has the capability to upload/sftp files to a remote Storage Server. The use of Multer is to provide multiple useful events while uploading your file to the server where your Node.js application is deployed.

If you want to upload file to remote storage server other than the server where your Node.js application is deployed then consider using these modules ssh2/sftp-upload/scp2. I have few code samples for file upload/sftp using these modules here: https://github.com/prabhash1785/NodeJS/tree/master/fileupload

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multer-sftp` from npm [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-sftp)!

Like,

```
const multer = require('multer'),
    sftpStorage = require('multer-sftp');

const sftp = {
    host: '192.XX.XXX.X',
    port: 22,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'psswddd'
  };

 const options = { 
    sftp,
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/data/uploads')
    }
  };
const storage = sftpStorage(options);

multer({ storage });
```